# Out-of-band communication between two PCs

Tags: usb, serial, raspberry-pi, python

I'm working on a little project.  In the project, data must be sent from a PC to another device.  Initially, I used a Raspberry Pi and life was good. I could communicate Python between the RPi and the PC via a USB to serial interface as the RPi has serial I/O pins. Eventually, my application out-grew the RPi and I needed more processing power. I am considering moving up to something like a NUC (chromebox).

I really DON'T want to use typical TCP/IP comms, I'd like to use something like a serial connection.  Something like USB-A to USB-A would be great but from what little reading I've done, that doesn't seem to work. If you had to use something other than a NIC to talk between two computers, what would you use?

Comment: If you don't mind the speed, you could use two USB-to-serial dongles back-to-back. I believe that at least some USB "transfer" cables are effectively this.

Comment: "I really DON'T want to use typical TCP/IP comms": why? Is it bidirectional? How fast do you want? Do you have a latency/realtime constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **REALLY** don't want to use TCP/IP and you want an off-the-shelf solution, then a USB-to-USB null modem cable will work. This is effectively two USB-to-serial adapters with Rx and Tx crossed in the middle. [This page](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBtoUSB.htm) has one option that you might like to try - there are likely many others available, and you could make your own from 2 USB-to-serial adapters as described.

That said, I would generally always choose TCP/IP over USB serial for convenience, unless there was some extraordinary reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

You should use TCP.  Other than merely saying you don't want to use TCP, you gave no valid reason for avoiding it.  There is no place in engineering for religious beliefs.  If you can't justify a decision with a good reason, then it's a bad decision.

TCP and the network stack below it is built into just about any modern operating system.  NIC cards are cheap and plentiful, and nowadays often even built right onto the motherboard.  The only hardware you may need beyond the PCs is a ethernet cable.  The app interface is not much different from a serial port, but the speed is greater and you get reliable and checked delivery.  The RJ-45 type ethernet is even ground-isolated.

There is nothing in what you said that indicates TCP isn't a good answer.